# video toggle in Processing 3

Tags: video, arduino, processing

I am trying to  toggle videos in Processing using arduino and PIR sensor. I am new to this, so here is what I want to achieve "video1" will be on loop when program is running, but whenever PIR sensor detects motion it will play "video" full length and then switch back to "video1" and continue looping until PIR sensor is inactive.

thanks in advance <3

edit: it kinda works but doesn't go back to the "video1" after "video" ends.

here is the code:

```
import processing.video.*;
import processing.serial.Serial;

static final int PORT_INDEX = 0, BAUDS = 9600;
String myString;

Movie video, video1;



void setup() {
  size(1920, 1088);
  video = new Movie(this, "movie.mov");
  video1 = new Movie(this, "movie1.mov");
  final String[] ports = Serial.list();
  printArray(ports);
  new Serial(this, ports[PORT_INDEX], BAUDS).bufferUntil(ENTER);
  frameRate(25);

  video.stop();
   video1.loop();
}


boolean isToggled;
boolean mo = false;

void movieEvent(Movie m) { 
      m.read(); 
}



void draw() {
  background(0);
  set(0,0,isToggled? video : video1);
  if (video.time() == 10.0) {
    isToggled = false;

  }
}

void serialEvent(final Serial s) {
  myString = s.readString().trim();
  redraw = true;

  if (myString.equals("Motion detected!")) {
    isToggled = true;
    video.play();
    println("skria"); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the Processing Video library has a bug precisely reporting the playback time and stopping/looping.

I recommend printing out `video.time()` in `draw()` as a debug measure because you might need to turn that very stricy `== 10.0` to a looser/less precise threshold range accounting for the possiblity of missing that exact timing.

For example

```
if (video.time() => 9.59) {
 isToggled = false;
}
```

Off-topic: 
Your code overall is nice and readable.
Bare in mind you could replace:

```
  background(0);
  set(0,0,isToggled? video : video1);
```

with:

`background(isToggled? video : video1);`
or `image(isToggled? video : video1,0,0);`

Alternatively you could use a third `Movie` reference which you point to either `video` or `video1` based on your case, removing the need for the condition, through forceing you to always ensure the reference is always assigned before usage.